# Persistence Unit SQLException No suitable driver

Tags: jakarta-ee, persistence, glassfish

I have a j2ee application deployed on GlassFish.
I have mysql jars in GlassFish's lib directory.
I am trying to use JPA, and my persistence file is:

```
<persistence-unit name="teamPU"
    transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>
        oracle.toplink.essentials.PersistenceProvider
    </provider>
    <class>com.team.dao.Roles</class>
    <properties>
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.driver"
            value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.url"
            value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test" />
        <property name="toplink.jdbc.user" value="root" />
        <property name="toplink.ddl-generation"
            value="create-tables" />
    </properties>
</persistence-unit>
```

i also have toplink-essentials* jars in lib.
When I call dao.find*, it throws the No suitable driver.
Don't I have all the jars where they should be?

Comment: do you have a stacktrace of the error?

Comment: Local Exception Stack: 
Exception [TOPLINK-4002] (Oracle TopLink Essentials - 2.1 (Build b60e-fcs (12/23/2008))): oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
Error Code: 0
 at oracle.toplink.essentials.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:305)
 at oracle.toplink.essentials.sessions.DefaultConnector.connect(DefaultConnector.java:102)
 at oracle.toplink.essentials.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:184)
 at oracle.toplink.essen

Comment: Are you using a connection pool? Does it connect?

Comment: I had to put the mysql driver jar in my java's lib directory. it was not good enough to just be in GlassFish's lib directory. it is now working, but it seems odd that I had to do this?

Comment: when you said you have them in the lib folder I think everyone thought you meant the GF lib folder. That folder is the appropriate place for your dependency jars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had this issue with a Java web app (Servlets/JSP) using JPA/toplink. It worked fine on my development system w/NetBeans deploying to Tomcat. When I deployed the web app to Tomcat on the production server, I'd get "java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver" and I saw toplink packages in the call stack. What's interesting is that I'm also using direct JDBC in my web app and that worked fine on the production server.

The fix was to copy the appropriate jdbc driver .jar to the jre6\lib\ext folder.

It would be nice to know why it's not enough to have the jdbc .jar put into the web app .war file in the case of toplink...